# How to access public properties of a List<class> by their ordinal position

Tags: c#, generic-list, ordinal

I have public properties of a class and my output detail line is being written like this:

```
public static long OutputListToFile(StreamWriter writer, List<DocMetaData> listData)
    {
        StringBuilder md = new StringBuilder();
        int rowcount = 0;
        foreach (var c in listData)
        {
            md.Append(c.Section); md.Append(DocMetaData.SEPARATOR);
            md.Append(c.DocClass); md.Append(DocMetaData.SEPARATOR);
            md.Append(c.Meeting); md.Append(DocMetaData.SEPARATOR);
            md.Append(c.Agency); md.Append(DocMetaData.SEPARATOR);
            md.Append(c.Country); md.Append(DocMetaData.SEPARATOR);
            md.Append(c.Comment); md.Append(DocMetaData.SEPARATOR);
            md.Append(c.Title); md.Append(DocMetaData.SEPARATOR);
            md.Append(c.Folder); md.Append(DocMetaData.SEPARATOR);
            md.Append(c.File); md.Append(DocMetaData.CARRIAGE_RETURN);
            try
            {
                writer.WriteLine(md.ToString());
                rowcount++;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Fatal("Error in OutputListToFile:\r\n", ex);
            }
        }
        return rowcount;
    }
```

The md.Append statements currently have to be placed in the above exact order so as to match with the routine that writes the very first line:

```
private void OutputColumnNamesAsFirstLine(StreamWriter writer)
    {
        StringBuilder md = new StringBuilder();
        PropertyInfo[] columns;
        columns = typeof(DocMetaData).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                                      BindingFlags.Instance);
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var columnName in columns)
        {
            i++;
            md.Append(columnName.Name); md.Append(DocMetaData.SEPARATOR);
        }
        writer.WriteLine(md.ToString());
    }
```

Is there a way the foreach loop in OutputListToFile could be rewritten such that I can eliminate this ordering dependency. Here is a snippet of the DocMetaData class:

```
 public class DocMetaData
{
    public const string SEPARATOR = "\t";       // horizontal tab is delimiter
    public const string CARRIAGE_RETURN = "\r";

    public string Section { get; set; }
    public string DocClass { get; set; }
    public string Meeting { get; set; }
    public string Agency { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Folder { get; set; }
    public string File { get; set; }
```

Comment: Note that the runtime is **not** required to order the results of `Type.GetProperties()`, and it may in fact **reorder** the results between calls.  So this implementation is in fact flawed!  That it continues to work is simply one possible outcome of the undefined behavior you are invoking.  A new release of the runtime, for example, could easily break your code.  You should at least impose your own ordering on the results of the `GetProperties()` call.  The `OutputListToFile()` method should then follow this same ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you want, but if you want to write the content of all properties in the same order they are in `column`, you can just use that:

```
foreach (var c in listData)
{
    foreach (var column in columns)
    {
        md.Append(column.GetValue(c, null));
    }
}
```

This code doesn't use the separator and terminator as your original code, but I'm sure you can easily fix that.

Comment: Thanks. I copied the "discovery" of columns from the other routine:  PropertyInfo[] columns;
columns = typeof(DocMetaData).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |                                                      BindingFlags.Instance); and then your inner loop works great!

Comment: As @cdhowie pointed out in a comment, doing it like this currently works, but may not always. You should fetch the list of columns once and share that between the two methods.

Answer (score 2):

If you would consider annotating the properties with an attribute, this solution would work:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class OrdinalPositionAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int Position { get; private set; }

    public OrdinalPositionAttribute(int position)
    {
        Position = position;
    }
}

public class DocMetaData
{
    public const string SEPARATOR = "\t";       // horizontal tab is delimiter
    public const string CARRIAGE_RETURN = "\r";

    [OrdinalPosition(0)]
    public string Section { get; set; }
    [OrdinalPosition(1)]
    public string DocClass { get; set; }
    [OrdinalPosition(2)]
    public string Meeting { get; set; }
    [OrdinalPosition(3)]
    public string Agency { get; set; }
    [OrdinalPosition(4)]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [OrdinalPosition(5)]
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    [OrdinalPosition(6)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [OrdinalPosition(7)]
    public string Folder { get; set; }
    [OrdinalPosition(8)]
    public string File { get; set; }

    private void OutputColumnNamesAsFirstLine(StreamWriter writer)
    {
        StringBuilder md = new StringBuilder();
        var columns = Utility.GetOrderedMembers(typeof(DocMetaData));

        int i = 0;
        foreach (var columnName in columns)
        {
            i++;
            md.Append(columnName.Name); md.Append(DocMetaData.SEPARATOR);
        }
        writer.WriteLine(md.ToString());
    }
}

public static class Utility
{
    public static IEnumerable<MemberInfo> GetOrderedMembers(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("type");

        return CreateGetOrderedMembersEnumerable(type);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<MemberInfo> CreateGetOrderedMembersEnumerable(Type type)
    {
        return from member in type.GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)

               let ordinal = member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(OrdinalPositionAttribute), true)
                                   .OfType<OrdinalPositionAttribute>().FirstOrDefault()

               where ordinal != null

               orderby ordinal.Position ascending

               select member;
    }
}
```

If you want to obtain the values of the properties, you will need to call `.Cast<PropertyInfo>()` on the `IEnumerable<MemberInfo>` returned by `GetOrderedMembers()`.

Comment: Wow! I just read your comment under the original post warning about the fragility of that technique. Thank you very much for posting a more elegant and robust proposed solution. It is a lot for me to absorb right now but I will revisit this tomorrow. Thank you for your time and attention.

Comment: No problem.  Note that my solution is kind of rough and was thrown together.  If you're doing this kind of thing a lot in your classes, you might settle on a standard way of doing it for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a `Dictionary<string, string>` for your DocMetaData (instead of a class) where the first is the field name and the second the value. Then you can retrieve the values using your columns array.